# How to align input boxes in 2 lines

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a form where I want 3 input boxes to the left and to the right. Now, I copied the code from a past project of mine where it worked but now it wont work in this new project. I've tried every text-align and float I know about. I really don't know what to do anymore.

This is the code i have for this so far.

```css
input[id=fname], input[id=lname], input[id=phone], input[id=city],i nput[id=email], input[id=birthday] {
    width: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
}


#left {
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right {
    width: 440px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    
    <head>
       <title>Employee Directory</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <div class="form">
           <form method="post">
               <div id="left">
                   <label>First Name</label>
                   <input id="fname" type="text" tabindex="1" >
                   
                   <label>Phone</label>
                   <input id="phone" type="phone" tabindex="3">
                   
                   <label>City</label>
                   <input id="city" type="text" tabindex="5">   
               </div>
               
               <div id="right" class="box">
                   <label>Last Name</label>
                   <input id="lname" type="text" tabindex="2">
                   
                   <label>Email</label>
                   <input id="email" type="email" tabindex="4">
                   
                   <label>Birthday</label>
                   <input id="bday" type="date" tabindex="6">
               </div> 
           </form>
       </div>
       
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: input at width : 420px , but #left at width:40px ? they overflow their container. you have a few display option but also you need to rethink input's width

Comment: The easiest to achieve this is to add a wrapper for the `#left` and `#right` with like a `div` than add a `display: flex` properties to the wrapper. [Check all the possibilities that you can achieve with flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the HTML and CSS a lot here. Use `display:grid` to align everything:

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 9px 20px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="post">
  <label>First Name
      <input name="fname" type="text">
  </label>
  <label>Last Name
      <input name="lname" type="text">
   </label>
  <label>Phone
      <input name="phone" type="phone">
  </label>
  <label>Email
      <input name="email" type="email">
    </label>
  <label>City
      <input name="city" type="text">
  </label>
  <label>Birthday
      <input name="bday" type="date">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make it so your order of inputs is left to right down the page as tabbing from first name to Phone and then back up to last name is not very intuitive (Although fixed with tabindex this can be default).

Here is how I would do it.

```css
input[id=fname], input[id=lname], input[id=phone], input[id=city],input[id=email], input[id=birthday] {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
}


#form_fields {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#form_fields label {
    width:50%;
}

#form_fields label input {
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    
    <head>
       <title>Employee Directory</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
       <div class="form">
           <form method="post">
               <div id="form_fields">
                   <label>First Name<br />
                       <input id="fname" type="text" />
                   </label>
                              
                   <label>Last Name<br />
                       <input id="lname" type="text" />
                   </label>
                   
                   <label>Phone<br />
                       <input id="phone" type="phone" />
                   </label>
                   
                   <label>Email<br />
                       <input id="email" type="email" />
                   </label>
                   
                   <label>City<br />
                       <input id="city" type="text" />   
                   </label>
                       
                   <label>Birthday<br />
                       <input id="bday" type="date" />
                   </label>
               </div> 
           </form>
       </div>
       
    </body>
    
</html>
```